# jQuery "scroll-to-top" where error message appears in form validation

Tags: jquery, validationerror

I'm trying to get this script to work:

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid)
{
    if($(".error").length > 0) 
    { 
        var firstErrorElement = $(".error").first(); 

        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:firstErrorElement.offset().top},'slow'); 
    }                                                 

    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Please see what I'm trying to do [here](http://asap.net.co).

Comment: Sorry, but is there a question here?

Comment: does anyone know where the problem in this code is?

Comment: function scrollToAnchor(aid){
            if($(".error").length > 0) { var firstErrorElement = $(".error").first(); 
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:firstErrorElement.offset().top},'slow');   }                                                 
                var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
            }

Answer (score 0):

this has been solved by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/123127/didier-ghys
http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/Kwhbv/

```js
$("#SurveyForm").validate({
    focusInvalid: false,
    invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
        
        if (!validator.numberOfInvalids())
            return;
        
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(validator.errorList[0].element).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        
    }
});
```